# (Angular 5) javascript Image onload in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to use `Image.onload = function () {}` in angular

my code

```
loadImage(path) {
  this.loadedImage = new Image();
  this.loadedImage.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
  this.loadedImage.src = path;

  this.loadedImage.onload = function () {
    this._PreviewHelper.changeModelTexture(this.model, this.loadedImage);     
  }
}
```

Is there a way to use this event on angular.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried arrow function `.onload = () => {`?

Comment: Yes, i have tried already it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by `didn't work`? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: You are instantiating a custom object (Image), which is crucial for your problem... yet you don't even mention what it is.

Comment: it is not executing onload funcation. (No error, does not go inside =>{})

Answer (score 21):

Try to make use of the angular built in functionality if you can.

In the loadImage function

```
this.imageSrc = path;
```

Create a function to be called on image load

```
onImageLoad() {
    // Do what you need in here
}
```

And in the template:

```
<img [src]="this.imageSrc" (load)="onImageLoad()" />
```

Comment: i am not using img tag. just created an object and assigned with base64 this.loadedImage.src = path;

Comment: How would you get the loaded image properties (height, width) inside onImageLoad() ?

Comment: (load)="onImageLoad($event)" may get the properties.

Comment: "this" keyword in template is an error, should be just `[src]="imageSrc"`

Answer (score 3):

`onload` is called if a proper image path is given.

If it still doesn't work then check 
   1) Where are calling the method `loadImage` ?
   2) Is there any issue with the preview helper line

Edit 1:

If you are using `function` then try the below:

```
this.loadedImage.onload = function() {
    let that = this;
    that._PreviewHelper.changeModelTexture(that.model, that.loadedImage);     
}
```

Otherwise, try this: (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzlmee)

```
this.loadedImage.onload = () => {
    this._PreviewHelper.changeModelTexture(this.model, this.loadedImage);     
  }
```

Comment: The code u shared on load will execute                                            
  `this.loadedImage.onload = function () {
      console.log('hihi')
    }`  (hihi is consoled) as = function() is not typescript so we can not access variables or functions in component

Comment: I have updated my answer for this scenario. Check it. Also, I have updated the stackblitz implementation

Comment: Neither  example of using let that = this nor the example of using the arrow function for the case of anonymous function to load image variable does not work for me. Better come up with other alternative that work for my case. BTW, I'm using Angular 10 though.